# Receive message prompt before sending Outlook mail, based on data in Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, prompt

We work with outsourcing and freelancers, and it is difficult to keep track of who is unavailable and until when.

I pieced together an Excel file in which a userform simplifies entering dates, people (entered through their email address) are unavailable, in the Excel worksheet.

The next step is to “connect” this Excel file to Outlook, so that when I click “Send” or enter an e-mail address, a macro:

1. checks if the entered e-mail address is in the worksheet of the Excel file
2. checks if the present moment falls between the dates of unavailability next to that name
3. gives a prompt message when both conditions are met to tell me this person is unavailable, and let me cancel sending the email.
4. optional: the message prompt has fields which are filled with the according period of unavailability for that person

Would it be possible to connect Excel to Outlook in this way, so that we can continue using Outlook to write our mails?

Simplified, it should look something like this:

```
Click “Send” in Outlook email window
Before sending, call Excel file (does not need to be visible)
Check e-mail address column (column A)
 Matches “To” field in Outlook email window?
    If No, Send email
    If Yes, Check “From” date column (column C) next to corresponding email address
     Present date is equal to or later than “From” date?
        If No, Send Email
        If Yes, Check “Until” Date column (column D): present date is earlier than or equal to present date?
            If Yes, message prompt: “Name (column B) is not available from “From” until “Until”. Do you still want to send the e-mail?
            Buttons:
                Yes: Send Email
                No: Close prompt, do not send email, but keep email open.
            If No, Send Email
```

Code for the userform in the Excel file:

```vb
Private Sub CommandDate1_Click()
    DatePicker1.Show
    AbsencePlannerUserForm.StartTextBox.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click()
    Call AbsencePlannerUserForm_Initialize
End Sub

Private Sub CommandDate2_Click()
    DatePicker2.Show
    AbsencePlannerUserForm.EndTextBox.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub EndTextBox_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub ExtraInfoTextBox_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub OKButton_Click()
    Dim M_Date As Date
    Dim M_Item As String

    M_Date1 = StartTextBox
    M_Date2 = EndTextBox
    M_Item = EmailTextBox
    M_Info = ExtraInfoTextBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LastRow = Abwesenheit1.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For rw = 2 To LastRow
        If Abwesenheit1.Cells(rw, "A") = M_Item And Cells(rw, "C") = M_Date1 _
          And Cells(rw, "D") = M_Date2 And Cells(rw, "E") = M_Info Then GoTo Passem
    Next rw
    GoTo NO_Dups
    
Passem:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Der Urlaub für " & M_Item & " vom " & M_Date1 & " bis zum " & _
      M_Date2 & " ist schon eingetragen."
    Exit Sub
    
NO_Dups:
    
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    
    'Make Abwesenheit1 active
    Abwesenheit1.Activate
    
    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    
    'Transfer information
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = EmailTextBox.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = StartTextBox.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = EndTextBox.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = ExtraInfoTextBox.Value
    
    Application.Visible = True
    Me.Hide
    
End Sub
    
Private Sub AbsencePlannerUserForm_Click()
    
End Sub
    
Private Sub AbsencePlannerUserForm_Initialize()
    'Empty EmailTextBox
    EmailTextBox.Value = ""
    
    'Empty StartTextBox
    StartTextBox.Value = ""
    
    'Empty EndTextBox
    EndTextBox.Value = ""
    
    'Empty ExtraInfoTextBox
    ExtraInfoTextBox.Value = ""
    
    'Set Focus on EmailTextBox
    EmailTextBox.SetFocus
End Sub
    
Sub open_form()
    Application.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Private Sub StartTextBox_Change()
    
End Sub
   
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    
End Sub
    
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.Visible = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. You will need to create a reference to Outlook through excel in the VBA environment. To do that:

Activate the outlook library from Tools/References

￼
(The number of the library might differ on your computer)

And then call outlook:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application

The you could set a condition and if it matched to show a user form with all the information of unavailability and add button that when clicked exits the sub and closes the outlook message.

If you post the code it will be easier to work on it but basically, call outlook, create a user form with a button to close everything if needed.

Comment: Hi Pablo, thank you for giving me something to go on.
I now activated the outlook object in Excel VBA.

Do I now need to write code in Outlook or Excel VBA, when I want Outlook to be my primary tool, and Excel just the source for the data Outlook will use for these conditions?

Unfortunately, my Excel VBA code is too long to comment.

Comment: Yes you can do that too. But outlook works a bit different than Excel in terms of macros, a bit more advanced I would say. This is a good website to learn about them: http://www.vboffice.net.  You will have to do the opposite, call Excel from Outlook but working mainly on the ‘On this session’ module

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it, I'm glad to hear that what I imagined is possible, albeit maybe more advanced than I handle. I'll just give it a try. If it heklps, I inserted the code in my main question.